# ios swift json data to dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I have following format of data from a php script

`{"Response":"OK","Data":{"ID":"1","data1":"sample1"}}`

I need to extract data1 using http in swift, below is the code, but the code is not working as expected, that is  `if let data = dict?["Data"] as? [[String:Any]] {` not giving any return.

```
   fetchDataFromDB { (dict, error) in
        if(dict?["Response"] as! String == "OK"){
            var dd = dict?["Data"] as? [String:Any]
            if let data = dict?["Data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for d in data {
                    if let data1 = d["data1"] as? String {
                       self.data1 = data1
                    }
                                       
              }
            }       
            
        }
```

The function fetchDataFromDB

```
func fetchDataFromDB(completion: @escaping ([String:Any]?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://test.com/get__details.php")!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                if let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]{
                    completion(array, nil)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (unused) line above is correct, it's a dictionary. And handle the error

```
fetchDataFromDB { (dict, error) in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    if let dict?["Response"] as? String == "OK",        
       let data = dict?["Data"] as? [String:Any],
       let data1 = data["data1"] as? String {
           self.data1 = data1
    }
}
```

And as the expected type of the root object is a dictionary name it accordingly

```
if let dictionary = try JSONSerialization...
```

---

Consider to use `Codable` to parse the JSON

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use `Codable` considering the json example that you gave your class should look like:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - ResponseDB
struct ResponseDB: Codable {
    let response: String
    let data: DataClass

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case response = "Response"
        case data = "Data"
    }
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id, data1: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case data1
    }
}
```

In order to decode the response to your class add this code to your class or a custom class:

```
// MARK: - Helper functions for creating encoders and decoders

func newJSONDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return decoder
}

func newJSONEncoder() -> JSONEncoder {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return encoder
}

// MARK: - URLSession response handlers

extension URLSession {
    fileprivate func codableTask<T: Codable>(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (T?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        return self.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completionHandler(nil, response, error)
                return
            }
            completionHandler(try? newJSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data), response, nil)
        }
    }

    func responseDBTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (ResponseDB?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        return self.codableTask(with: url, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

To read value from url:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.responseDBTask(with: YOUR_URL_HERE) { responseDB, response, error in
   if let responseDB = responseDB {
      if responseDB.response == "OK" {
         self.data1 = responseDB.data.data1
       }
   }
}
task.resume()
```